# Intersection of modules is equal to product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

If $B$  is a commutative ring and let $\mathcal{Q}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{Q}_n$ ideals relative primes.

Let $M$ be a $R$-module. I don't sure if this is true. Then

$$(\mathcal{Q}_1\cap\cdots \cap\mathcal{Q}_n)M \supseteq \mathcal{Q}_1M\cap \cdots \cap \mathcal{Q}_n M\ ?$$

i.e. $(\mathcal{Q}_1\cap\cdots \cap\mathcal{Q}_n)M =\mathcal{Q}_1M\cap \cdots \cap \mathcal{Q}_n M $.

Thank you all.

Comment: This is just a consequence of the Chinese Remainder Theorem (assuming you mean pairwise relatively prime)

Comment: why is a consequence ?

Comment: https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/chinese-remainder-theorem-for-modules-part-2/